# Make an HTTP request from a Load Balancer to a Cluster IP

Tags: azure-aks

## Question

We have deployed a Load Balancer and a Cluster IP to Azure Kubernetes Service like this:

[image]

How can we make an HTTP request from the Load Balancer to the Cluster IP? The Load Balancer has an `HttpClient` with the following code:

[image]

That call to `GetAsync` receives a 404 response for `http://10.0.162.73/debug` and `http://webapp/debug` as the `url`.

## Research and Comments

The `ClusterIP` ought to work for the internal `LoadBalancer`.

> ClusterIP creates an internal IP address for use within the AKS cluster. This Service is good for internal-only applications that support other workloads within the cluster. This is the default that's used if you don't explicitly specify a type for a Service.

I think we're trying for the request pathway that the big blue lines indicates here and that ends with pod-to-pod communication.

```
User > Load Balancer > Node > Pod > Pod
```

[image]

## Troubleshooting

Steps from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/connection-issues-application-hosted-aks-cluster

1. Is pod running? YES. `kubectl get pods -n default`
2. Do logs seem good? YES. `kubectl logs webapi-...`
3. Is pod exposed as service. YES. `kubectl get svc -n default`
4. Does service have endpoint? YES. `kubectl describe svc webapi -n default`

[image]